# What parts, if any, of the spellcasting rules apply to Savage Sorcery?

Tags: spellcasting, stars-without-number

Codex of the Black Sun includes a focus called Savage Sorcery (p. 91), along with rules for spellcasting.

Savage Sorcery's level 1 use is described as a "Main Action invocation". While "Invocation" is occasionally used throughout the Codex of Dark Sun as a synonym for "Spell", it's equally used to refer specifically to the vocal part of spellcasting.

So the question is: What parts, if any, of the "Casting Spells" rules on page 21 apply to Savage Sorcery? Specifically:

Does it have to be declared at the beginning of the turn (and presumably would then be subject to failure on injury)?

Can it be used in armor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the author of *Stars Without Number*:

> So the question is: What parts, if any, of the "Casting Spells" rules on page 21 apply to Savage Sorcery? Specifically:
>
> Does it have to be declared at the beginning of the turn (and presumably would then be subject to failure on injury)?

Level 1 can be done any time you have a Main Action available and need not be declared beforehand. Level 2 functions exactly as normal spellcasting, except it converts the spell to direct damage.

> Can it be used in armor?

GM's call, but I'd generally allow it, since wearing heavy armor makes it impossible to use your other spells without the Armored Technique focus, and there will be very few situations where a caster would rather wear heavy armor than have access to their spellcasting abilities. The only generally-applicable situation is if they've run dry of spells for the day.

Comment: Thank you so much for discovering our site and answering this question. We very much welcome [game designers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6507/is-there-an-established-way-to-handle-a-games-designer-on-the-site) and love to get your answers. As the designer, can you help to flesh out your answer by adding the relevant rules that help support it? Your opinion/judgement is still meaningful, but answers here still need to be supported and you're in the best place to do that as the designer! Thank you again!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. We're glad to have you here, and hope you stick around! :)